# All bootstrap columns are appearing in the same row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I know its going to be a silly problem, but I am a newbie and its bugging me for a few hours. I am following a container > row > col structure still all my cols are appearing in a same row. As per bootstrap all there should be only 12 columns in a row, and all remaining columns should appear in the next line.
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row m-3 p-3">
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">akjsdajkshd
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't find whats wrong here, will appreciate some help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDo25.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your use case in a [CodePen sandbox](https://codepen.io/rchrdchn/pen/oNbGYRN) using the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm">3</div>
        <div class="col-sm">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm">5</div>
        <div class="col-sm">6</div>
        <div class="col-sm">7</div>
        <div class="col-sm">8</div>
        <div class="col-sm">9</div>
        <div class="col-sm">10</div>
        <div class="col-sm">11</div>
        <div class="col-sm">12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From Bootstrap's documentation on its [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/):

> The above example creates equal-width columns on small, medium,
> large, and extra large devices using our predefined grid classes.
> Those columns are centered in the page with the parent `.container`.

When using Bootstrap, you don't necessarily need to use `container-fluid`, unless you want to set the container `width: 100%` at all breakpoints (different devices width: Small ≥ 576px, Medium ≥ 768px, Large ≥ 992px, and so on...). See [Bootstrap documentation regarding its Container here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/).

If you want to set all `div` to have `text-center`, you could do the following to avoid adding unnecessary classes to your `divs`.

```
<div class="container text-center">
...
</div>
```

I hope this helps solve your problem! Let me know if you have follow-up questions

Comment: Thanks for answering Richard but the problem is if I add few more divs lets say 13, 14... They all appear in a same line. As per bootstrap we can have only 12 columns layout, so why are these columns not moving to the next line. Am I missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact reason why Bootstrap keeps adding the extra divs on the same row. If I were to use more than 12 columns I would create a separate `<div class="row">...</div>` for the next stack of columns. See an example here (docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal) or on my updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/rchrdchn/pen/oNbGYRN

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using fluid container? bootstrap design to work as responsive accordingly.
Make below snippet **full screen** you will get to know, in this approach when ever grid increase  more than 12 it will automatically added in new line

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">5</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```